# Alternatives to Protocol Buffers

Tags: serialization, messaging

I'd like a basic message passing/RPC system. I could use a serialisation system but I want some sort of verification to ensure both ends are synchronised. I've looked at Google Protocol Buffers, but I'm not too keen on code generation. What are other alternatives?

Answer (score 15):

You can look at http://msgpack.org/

Answer (score 6):

Maybe thrift would do.
http://thrift.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Cap'n Proto, which is designed by Kenton Varda, who worked for Google as the primary author of Protocol Buffers version 2 (the open source one now everybody uses). It has a feature called "time travel" that worths looking (a feature that makes round trips for fetching dependent data to and from server into one trip).

http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

I really love [Cap’n Proto](https://capnproto.org/)!

Awesome serialization + RPC capabilities, [open source](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto), great schema language...

(Authored by Kenton Varda, the primary author of Protocol Buffers version 2)